# Traits With implicit Class Scala

Tags: scala, amazon-sns

On my example. I want to find a way to use Implicit value in my connection to aws-sns.

```
object SNSClient {

}

class SNSClient {
  val region =
    try {
      val prop = new Properties()
      prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"))
      prop.getProperty("aws.region")
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => println("error")
    }

 // In this method Scala wont compile
 def providesSNSClient(): AmazonSNS = {
      AmazonSNSClientBuilder
             .standard
             .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey.toString(), secretKey.toString())))
             .withRegion(region) //Error compile
             .build()
  }
}

 /**
  * Rich prpierties
  */
 trait RegionsImplict {
   /**
    * Return default value if it does not provide Regions.EU_WEST_1
    */
   implicit class RegionB(region: String){
     def asRegion: Regions = Regions.values().find(_.name == region).getOrElse(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
   }

 }
```

So far so good I want to call my function asRegion on my line code .withRegion(region)//Error compile

Comment: Automagic implicit conversion is generally evil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `region` is NOT a `String`, so the implicit conversion doesn't kick in.

You can see this with the following simplified Scala REPL example:

```
scala> val region = try { "value" } catch { case e: Exception => println("error") }
region: Any = value  // <--- notice type is Any
```

Why? Because some of the code paths (i.e. the `catch` phrase) do not product a String, so the compiler has to "settle" for the closest common supertype, which is `Any`.

To fix this, you should either abort on exception, or provide some default value, otherwise some code paths simply won't produce a String. For example:

```
val region =
  try {
    val prop = new Properties()
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"))
    prop.getProperty("aws.region")
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => println("error"); "us-east" // Default!
  }
```

**NOTE**: as commented, it is not recommended to use implicit conversions so lightly, *especially* for common types such as Strings - they might kick in when you don't expect them to and make code harder to read.

Comment: When take the trace:  overloaded method value withRegion with alternatives: (x$1: String)com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClientBuilder <and> (x$1: com.amazonaws.regions.Regions)com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClientBuilder cannot be applied to (Any)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your NOTE, I wan to find ways to apply Implicit